# Google App Engine: Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have read the manual here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html

But I want to do a task at some specific times:

```
- description: do this cron
  url: /do-this-cron
  schedule: every day 08:15,12:15,16:15
```

Is this legit?

I havent seen any other examples where times are seperated by comma.

Answer (score 6):

No, the schedule format doesn't support comma-separated times. You can do this instead:

```
- description: do this cron
  url: /do-this-cron
  schedule: every 4 hours from 08:15 to 16:15
```